# One UICollectionView out of several not showing

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

Heres's a puzzler:

I have a collection view that works great when run through Xcode, however when distributed as an ad-hoc build (think, testflight), only on the first open, the collection view appears blank.

The following are verified:

- Is visible
- Has expected frame
- Is added to a view
- Can put a label into it and the label appears
- Does not call dataSource/delegate methods
- Does not call FlowLayout subclass methods
- Occurs on any version (7/8/9) on any device

No amount of reloadData, setDelegate, nor setDataSource will cause it to call its delegate/dataSource methods.

I have several other collection views in the paginated scroll view that work fine. Only this collection view is problematic.

One final note, if I install a build via Xcode, delete it, then install one of the ad-hoc builds, they work fine!? Once an Xcode build has been installed on a device, the collection view never appears blank again on first run on that device.

Comment: Is this the first view of the app? What I'm trying to establish is, might there be a problem with the app's opening dance?

Comment: No. This is a few views deep. Oh, one more piece of info. If you reset rootViewController by re-instantiating storyboard's initialViewController, once the views load up the collectionView re-appears. It's almost as if this could be described that "The first time the xib is loaded" instead of "the first time the app is run". Note, storyboard loads VCs that end up loading other xibs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did eventually figure this out. At one point Apple added an exception/warning when modifying UI from a background thread. I found that a callback was reloading the collection view on a background thread which caused the wonky behavior.